# Java Serialization vs XML

Tags: java, json, xml, serialization

I am basically interested in analyzing the object form that we need to send to client over network in client-server model.

i need to know what are the criteria that we need to consider when we choose xml and java serialization respectively. which is the best approach to choose for object transform over network.

why serialization came into picture when we have already XML,JSON transformation already

Edit :

I wanted to know the why serialization is being used when we have XML/JSON already being used before its invention

Comment: Java serialization is only natively portable between Java endpoints. That makes the requirement quite steep already. Add to that the fact that it's tricky to get right, it seems to me we have a loser. But that's just me.

Comment: Then XML cannot be used between Java endpoints.?. Whats the edge that serialization gives over xml between Java endpoints

Comment: Java has a built in XML serializer, but there are plenty of widely used SAX and DOM parsers. I would say XML is the best supported serialization for Java.

Comment: We didn't have XML/JSON already. Java Serialization dates from 1997 at the latest. XML certainly wasn't usable for serialization at that time and JSON had never been heard of.

Answer (score 1):

If XML and JSON works for you I would stick with that. It is much easier to log and check it is doing what you believe it should be.

Java Serialization has many advantages however unless you need these they are unlikely to be the best solution.

- it is built in, no extra JAR is required.
- it is integrated with existing remote APIs
- it supports all serializable object types and graphs. (XML and JSON only support trees of data, not typed objects)
- it supports data types and you only write each reference once.

However Java Serialization is not

- very efficient
- easy to read/validate as a human.
- flexible for schema changes esp changes in package or class names.
- portable outside Java.

Personally, my preference is YAML. This is because

- it was designed to be human readable where as XML is a subset of SGML and JSON a sub-set of Javascript.
- it supports graphs and data types.
- it is almost as efficient as JSON (it's a bit slower as it does more)

Comment: YAML is interesting. I don't know why oracle is not incorporating serialization optimizations done as part of Hadoop project to make current serialization efficient.

Comment: @ravindra the priority in Oracle is increased security rather than efficiency. (and supporting the cloud)

Comment: @ravindra Or maybe the changes aren't compatible, or they don't know about them, or they have other plans. Anything is possible. You should ask them.